# Is it possible to measure 10/100baseT with a regular oscilloscope probe?

Tags: oscilloscope, ethernet, probe

I want to measure the waveforms of ethernet signals (both RX and TX at the same time) using the [DSO-X 1024G](https://www.mouser.co.il/ProductDetail/Keysight/DSOX1204G-D1200BW2A-200?qs=DPoM0jnrROXHtc5fpoputg%3D%3D) oscilloscope (200 MHz, 1 GS/s, 4 channels).

My plan is to connect 2 oscilloscope probes across 2 pairs (TX/RX).
Like this (but 2 pairs not 1):
[image: Analyzing actual Ethernet encoding | Networking tutorial (4 of 13)]
*From [Ben Eater - Analyzing actual Ethernet encoding | Networking tutorial (4 of 13)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8CmibhvZ0c)*

Do I need differential probes to measure more than 1 signal at a time? (Since I want to measure both RX and TX)

*BTW - I know there are better ways to measure Ethernet signals. I want to use an oscilloscope to learn about ethernet encodings and decode the line coding myself manually.*

Comment: How do you intend to decode 100Base-TX manually? While interesting in theory, It is unlikely that you can discriminate between transmission of IDLE symbol and actual data packets, as they are randomized with a scrambler.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't think about it. How do NICs do it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each twisted pair in the Ethernet cable is isolated individually with a transformer at the sending and receiving ends. This means that you can hook one probe with its ground clip and signal input to each pair. You don't need differential probes.

The signals are already fully isolated, so it doesn't matter if you ground one wire of a twisted pair.

Signal integrity will be slightly degraded, but unless you're using a 5+ meter cable, this is unlikely to cause a problem.

Comment: Isn't it a problem that all the `-` would be connected together?

Comment: Like if we have: RX-, RX+, TX-, TX+ then (RX- and TX-) would be connected, no?

Comment: @ori6151 connecting all the `-` together will increase crosstalk in the cable run,  if you probe on a short cable there will probably not be enough distortion caused to be a problem for the data. - so probe between a switch ans a nearby attached device, or  instead probe on the inner side of the ethernet transformer in the device or switch.  adding clip-on ferrites to the coaxial scope probe leads will also help.